# On mouseover Event Listener not changing color of grid item/div

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseover, event-listener

Kind of a JavaScript noob here. I'm using DOM manipulation for a project and need to make it so that the grid items in my container change color after being hovered on. Why won't my **hoverColor() function** do anything? I assume that it is a problem with my "grid-item" class not working right.

I haven't adjusted the container sizing options yet, just trying to make the event listener work first.

```js
//query selectors
const container = document.querySelector('#container');


//Function that creates GRID
function addDivs(rows, cols){
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
    for (i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++){
      let square = document.createElement("div");
      square.classList.add('grid-item');
      container.appendChild(square);
    }
  hoverColor();
}

//function that creates a random color
let randomColor = function() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

//function that changes div color uponed being hovered
function hoverColor() {
  let item = document.querySelector('.grid-item');
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    item.style.backgroundColor = `${randomColor()}`;
  });
}

//grid creationg
addDivs(16, 16);
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

#container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems with your code:

1. Most fundamentally, you forgot to call your `randomColor` function. You were trying to stringify the function value itself as a CSS color value, which was never going to work. `randomColor()` is instead what you wanted, the color *returned* by the function.
2. Your function would have only worked on the first grid item, because you were using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which only selects the first HTML element in the collection of matched elements. You instead want to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and iterate through the collection, adding the event listener to each.

See working example below, with both fixes made:

```js
//query selectors
const container = document.querySelector('#container');


//Function that creates GRID
function addDivs(rows, cols){
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
    for (i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++){
      let square = document.createElement("div");
      square.classList.add('grid-item');
      container.appendChild(square);
    }
  hoverColor();
}

//function that creates a random color
let randomColor = function() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

//function that changes div color uponed being hovered
function hoverColor() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
  items.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      item.style.backgroundColor = `${randomColor()}`;
    });
  });
}

//grid creationg
addDivs(16, 16);
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

#container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dang just bet me to it haha.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Mistakes you did:

You have to attach the eventListener to every element. For starters, querySelector only takes first element. Even if you did use querySelectorAll, you would get a NodeList (sort of an array of Elements), you would still need to loop through each and add the event listener to every one.

In my solution I just add it immediately after you create it in the loop you present in addDivs. Saves looping twice.
You can then reference to the hoverColor function as I did in my example.

In the hoverColor function you will, by default, receive an Event($event) object (in your case MouseEvent). Among multiple properties, the Event object will have a target property which references your Element. You can then modify the style.backgroundColor property to the color of your choice.
Hope it is what you have wanted.

```
//query selectors
const container = document.querySelector('#container');


//Function that creates GRID
function addDivs(rows, cols){
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
    for (i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++){
      let square = document.createElement("div");
      square.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverColor);
      square.classList.add('grid-item');
      container.appendChild(square);
    }
}

//function that creates a random color
let randomColor = function() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

//function that changes div color uponed being hovered
function hoverColor($event) {
  const item = $event.target;
  item.style.backgroundColor = `${randomColor()}`;
}

//grid creationg
addDivs(16, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to your problem

```js
//query selectors
const container = document.querySelector('#container');


//Function that creates GRID
function addDivs(rows, cols){
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
    for (i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++){
      let square = document.createElement("div");
      square.classList.add('grid-item');
      container.appendChild(square);
    }
  hoverColor();
}

//function that creates a random color
let randomColor = function() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

//function that changes div color uponed being hovered
function hoverColor() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item'); // Get all the elements with .grid-item (not just the first one
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { // Add for loop to add an event listener to all .grid-item elements
    items[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      items[i].style.backgroundColor = `${randomColor()}`; // randomColor function not being called 
                                                           // randomColor -> randomColor()
    });
  }
}

//grid creationg
addDivs(16, 16);
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

#container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## What I changed

### `querySelector()`

`querySelector()` to `querySelectorAll()`.

`querySelector()` will only select the first element it finds in the document `querySelectorAll()` will select every element in the document with that selector.

### `randomColor`

`randomColor` to `randomColor()`

`randomColor` will return the function `randomColor()` will run the function.

### Added a `for` loop

The `for` loop adds an event listener to all the elements with the class name `.grid-item`.